# Postfix stops working when /var mounted with noexec

Tags: postfix

I have `/var` on a separate partition, mounted with `noexec,nodev,nosuid`. Sending email through postfix does not work, I have following errors in my log:

```
postfix:  fatal: unknown service: smtp/tcp
postfix:  warning: private/smtp socket: malformed response
postfix:  warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtp pid 6569 exit status 1
postfix:  warning: transport smtp failure -- see a previous warning/fatal/panic logfile record for the problem description
postfix:  warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtp: bad command startup -- throttling
```

When I remount `/var` as `exec` and restart postfix, all works fine.

I am aware of this [bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=257096), but as far as I can tell, my postfix is not running in `chroot`. Why does postfix need `exec` permissions on `/var` then ?

Comment: The bug report says that Postfix has some `*.so` libraries located in `/var/spool/postfix/lib`. I can't verify this because I'm not using Postfix, but if that's true, than it's probably the reason why it won't work with `noexec`. Linux won't allow an application to map executable pages from a `noexec` filesystem, and that includes libraries.

Comment: But the bugreport refers to a situation, when `postfix` is run in `chroot`. AFAICT, I am not running postfix in `chroot`.

Comment: Yes, but [message 22 in that bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=257096#22) seems to imply that just using `noexec` on `/var` alone will already cause the error.

Comment: `lsof`does not show any `*.so` libraries open from `/var`

Comment: Does `lsof` list any `*.so` files opened in `/var` when it's mounted *without* `noexec`? Also, can you post the result of `ls -l /var/spool/postfix/lib` so we can at least establish if there are actually any libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, some components of postfix run in chroot by default (default installation of Debian Wheezy). For instance, following is the `smtp` line from `/etc/postfix/master.cf`

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
```

when I changed `-` to `n` the problem disappeared.